# How to add Facebook share button to share a youtube video you've embedded on your site

Tags: html, facebook-sharer

I have a webpage where I've embedded a youtube video. I need to add a facebook share button to this page to share the youtube video (not to share the webpage, only the video)

I added the following HTML code and managed to get it done.

```
<center><div id='pageshare' title='Share This With Your Friends'><div class='sbutton' id='fb'><image src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net//rsrc.php//v1//yg//r//yZiDLhSvAE9.gif'></image><a name='fb_share' type='box_count' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+location+"'>Share</a></div></center>
```

but then it justs add one image of a share button which is not what you really see in other places. (Here location is a variable which contains the url of my youtube video)

When I used this code

```
<center><div id='pageshare' title='Share This With Your Friends'><div class='sbutton' id='fb'><a name='fb_share' type='box_count' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+location+"'>Share</a><script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share?' type='text/javascript'></script></div></center>
```

I'm getting the correct fb share button, but it's not sharing the video instead it's sharing the url of my webpage.

Can someone help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanx for showing it. Seems like I can't add HTML code in here. I'll add them to the comment . This is the 1st HTML code I was referring to. <center><div id='pageshare' title='Share This With Your Friends'><div class='sbutton' id='fb'><image src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net//rsrc.php//v1//yg//r//yZiDLhSvAE9.gif'></image><a name='fb_share' type='box_count' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+location+"'>Share</a></div></center>

Comment: This is the second HTML code <center><div id='pageshare' title='Share This With Your Friends'><div class='sbutton' id='fb'><a name='fb_share' type='box_count' href='http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u="+location+"'>Share</a><script src='http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share?' type='text/javascript'></script></div></center>

Comment: @Jan - Thanx I found a way to fix it. Now you can see the code in the question itself. looking forward to an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
<a name="fb_share" type="box_count" href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php" rel="nofollow" alt="Share">Share</a>
<script src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"></script>
```